# MYSQL "You have an error in your SQL syntax" with LIKE command

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT cricketTarget FROM ifTable WHERE  ifAlias LIKE '06K284646%';
```

And MYSQL answer is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '06K284646%'' at line 1
```

What is the reason of this?

Comment: Where did you get it? in php?

Comment: This looks valid to me and runs appropriately ... try wrapping `ifAlias` in backticks.

Comment: The excess space wouldn't cause problems I believe. Make sure, you've got the spelling of `ifAlias` down right. The message tells you, that the error is straight in front of LIKE...and that's the column name.

Comment: can we see the table structure?

Comment: Like Refugnic Eternium sad the problem was in ifAlias spelling...

Answer (score 0):

use ifAlias between `` signs 
because it looks like ifAlias is a keyword

Comment: It would seem that way, but I just can't figure out what this keyword would do...

Comment: `IFALIAS` is not a listed [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Odd that it would require special treatment.

Comment: i think kiril bazarow has changed sql when asking the question. ifAlias is not ifAlias but maybe `table` or `key`. i would wait for his answer to that.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT cricketTarget FROM ifTable WHERE  ifAlias LIKE '%06K284646%';
                                                    // ^ Add a percentage here.
```